# Does using beyondcode/laravel-websockets need pusher APP/KEY?

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-websockets

To implement chat In  Laravel 8/vue 2.6 I added beyondcode/laravel-websockets
and reading some manuals I found that I need to use pusher packages, like
laravel-echo and pusher-js not not pusher App API. So I tried to make as in .env :

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=myId
PUSHER_APP_KEY=myKey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=mySecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

and in resources/js/bootstrap.js :

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'myKey',
    wsHost: 601,
    disableStats: true,
    forceTLS: false
});
```

In config/app.php I uncommented line :

```
 App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

In config/broadcasting.php :

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    'connections' => [
        'pusher' => [
            'driver'  => 'pusher',
            'key'     => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret'  => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id'  => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster'   => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
                'port'      => 6001,
                'scheme'    => 'http',

                'useTLS' => false,
            ],
        ],
        'ably'   => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key'    => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver'     => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

and in routes/channels.php :

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user, $id) {
    \Log::info(  varDump($user, ' routes/channels.php -1 $user::') ); // I DO NOT SEE THESE log lines
//    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
    return $user;
});
```

and in config/websockets.php :

```
<?php

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Dashboard\Http\Middleware\Authorize;

return [

    'dashboard' => [
        'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
    ],

    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],

    'app_provider' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\ConfigAppProvider::class,

    'allowed_origins' => [
        //
    ],

    'max_request_size_in_kb' => 250,

    'path' => 'laravel-websockets',

    'middleware' => [
        'web',
        Authorize::class,
    ],

    'statistics' => [
        'model' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Models\WebSocketsStatisticsEntry::class,

        'logger' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Logger\HttpStatisticsLogger::class,

        'interval_in_seconds' => 60,

        'delete_statistics_older_than_days' => 60,

        'perform_dns_lookup' => false,
    ],

    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

        'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
    ],

    'channel_manager' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManagers\ArrayChannelManager::class,
];
```

Running server I see :

```
user@os:app_path$ php artisan websockets:serve
Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...
New connection opened for app key myKey.
Connection id 447562709.864005085 sending message {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"447562709.864005085\",\"activity_timeout\":30}"}
...
```

RunningWebSockets Dashboard at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets
```

is connected with success with many messages,

But trying to post new event I see error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbWAI.jpg

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"data":["The data must be a valid JSON string."]}}
```

But in the brwosers console I see error :

```
app.js:119179 WebSocket connection to 'ws://0.0.2.89/app/myKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false' failed:
```

It fails with "myKey". Maybe it some options not to use pusher server key?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't work very well.
I'm having the same problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the credentials are the same on both the server and the client. You are setting the key value as `PUSHER_APP_KEY=myKey` in the client. What is the value of the variable used in the `config/broadcasting.php` file
and `config/websockets.php` : `key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),`.

[Source](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher#configuring-websocket-apps): *Make sure to use the same app id, key and secret as in your broadcasting configuration section. Otherwise broadcasting events from Laravel will not work.*

You will also need to ensure you use a valid JSON payload from the debug console.

[Source](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/debugging/dashboard#event-creator): *Simply enter the channel, the event name and provide a valid JSON payload to send it to all connected clients in the given channel.*

Comment: Yes, checking these parameters I see that they all reference 'myKey' value in .env

Also I have :
    key: 'myKey', 
in Echo options of resources/js/bootstrap.js

Searching in net for possible decisions I found some parameters not clear for :
useTLS in pusher.options of config/broadcasting.php 
and  in forceTLS in Echo options of resources/js/bootstrap.js

Are there some additive parameters with which pusher API parameters are ignored
and pusher App API is needed?